# Using python threadpool or similar, to process more records than cores

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multiprocessing

I have yet to write any code for this, so I'm just trying to determine the CORRECT way to do it.

I have a small app that will accept multiple records of input which it stores until the user presses the "Go" button.  (pyQt gui).  Once they user presses Go, the app will spawn 1 thread per core via a threadpool.  Each thread will be passed it's record number to process on creation.  It will then retrieve and then process the data, and return the results.  (OK, or failed at step X).

Here's the question:  There were UNDOUBTEDLY be cases where there are more records than there are cores to process them initially.  So, What is the BEST way handle this threadpool with regards to looping while there are records to do, starting the threads?

I've considered just having a big while or a for loop, but I figure there's probably a better way, and there might actually already be something in place to handle it.

Thanks!

Comment: **threads** as such in Python do not run in parallel, only concurrently. You need to use the [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) module. Use the primitives there, no need to reinvent the wheel yet again.

Comment: How does it process the records? Is it mostly by fetching data over a network? In that case threads will do fine, no need for processes.

Comment: This will all run on the same box.  So, the data fetches will be local, and via a public method in the base class.  (Basically a "getter").

Comment: OK @ Antti Haapala, I've read about multiprocessing, and it SOUNDS like what I want, but that allows me to clarify the question a little more.

Assuming that I create a pool:

"with Pool(processes=coreCount) as pool:"

I can then create processes via "pool.apply_async" the 1st time through.  This brings me to respawning them once they finish.  So, say I have 4 processes, and 8 pieces of data.  I want the threads to start, and when they finish, I want to give them their next chunk of data.  (Without waiting for all 4 to finish).  Is there a provision for that?